# Solving $\sin(4k-22) = \cos(6k-13)$

Tags: trigonometry

My niece asked for help with an SAT prep question. We are given that

$$\sin a = \cos b$$

where the angles are both acute and $a=4k-22$ and $b=6k-13$.

The only way we could think to solve it is by plotting and using fzero. But since it's an SAT problem, I assume there should be an approach that doesn't require a calculator.

Is there some trig identity I'm overlooking?

Comment: "Is there some trig identity I'm overlooking?"  yes,  $\cos b = \sin (90 - b)$  so $\sin a = \sin (90-b)$.  But *DO* be careful.   $\sin N =\sin M$ doesn't *always* mean $N=M$.  Does it in this case (when $a,b$ are both acute)?

Comment: Whenever you see _cosine_, think _complimentary sine_ (that is, the sine of an angle is the complimentary sine of the complimentary angle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overlooking some identities.
$$
\bbox[yellow,5pt, border:2px solid red]{
\sin A = \cos B \iff A+B = 90^\circ 
}\quad \textrm{(for A and B between 0 and 90 degrees)} \\
\bbox[yellow,5pt, border:2px solid red]{
\sin A = \cos B \iff A-B = 90^\circ 
}\quad \textrm{(for A between 0 and 90 degrees,B between 0,-90)} \\
\bbox[yellow,5pt, border:2px solid red]{
\sin A = \cos B \iff B-A = 90^\circ 
}\quad \textrm{(for B between 0 and 90 degrees,A between 0,-90)} 
$$

From here, of course, you get $4k-22 = 90-(6k-13)$
for the first case, $(6k-13) - (4k-22) = 90$ for the second case, and $(4k-22) - (6k-13) = 90$ for the third case.

Comment: There is also the condition $A-B=90$.

Comment: @Bernard What is $A_B$? Ok, seen the edit, but both angles are given acute. Otherwise I don't see a unique solution to this problem. But thank you for pointing it out, I will include it.

Comment: When you write $\sin A=\cos B \iff A+B = 90$ that is assuming $A,B$ are both  (positive) acute.  You could also have $A-B = 90$

Comment: @fleablood Fine, I will edit the answer then. I was of the thinking that acute meant between 0 and 90 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite $\sin(4k-22) = \cos(6k-13)$ as

$$\cos(90-4k+22) - \cos(6k-13)=2\sin\frac{99-2k}2 \sin\frac{115-10k}2 =0$$

which leads to $\frac{99+2k}2 =n\pi,\>\>\>\>\> \frac{134-10k}2 =n\pi$
and the solutions $k= n\pi-\frac{99}2,\> \frac{n\pi}5-\frac{67}5$.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a right triangle with acute angle $a$. The soh-cah-toa rule implies the other angle is $b$. Triangle angles add up to $180^\circ$.